# Красные метки отображаются серыми при редактировании

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, мета

На [этой странице](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0/info) правильно отображаются красные метки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при [редактировании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/12) они отображаются серым цветом:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Interesting, this tag doesn't have css class `s-tag_ moderator`, but it have to =/

Comment: [Соответствующий вопрос на общей Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354929/383809)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теперь все 3 варианта меток отображаются корректно:

[image: скриншот]