# На мете статусы посинели и рамка пропала

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, мета

При редактировании меток у вопроса статусные метки (как и все остальные показываются с синим фоном, хотя должны с красным). Также у обязательных меток не отображается рамка. Не уверен, сделаны ли метки синими вместо серых намеренно, но полное отсутствие отличительных признаков - явный косяк. В поле меток все метке тоже одинаковые.

[image: скриншот выбора статусных меток]

[image: скриншот выбора обязательных меток]

[image: скриншот меток]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Красные метки отображаются серыми при редактировании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10673/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8), Ага, такой эффект уже давно. По-моему этот вопрос про тоже ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, не думаю. Скорее всего совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, но пофиксили одновременно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправлено, скорее всего, вместе с [Красные метки отображаются серыми при редактировании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10673/178988).

[image: скриншот]